# How to run Karate API automation script on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, karate

we have created our API automation framework using Karate successfully. Now we are planning to run the automated scripts on AWS EC2 instance. Can somebody help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

a) If the AWS instances have a JRE included, use the "fat jar": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

b) Use Docker to easily use Maven and Java without installing anything extra: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide